# Configure a tunnel between a public server and clients

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I have an Ubuntu Server running under Google Cloud with a public IP address assigned and remote clients, each with a different public IP address (as they are behind different routers).

With that, I would like to create a tunnel between the server and those clients evading router configurations like port enabling for the client side and make the clients accessible through the internet for remote connection with the traffic passing through the server.

So far I have thought in a public DHCP server and making those client connect to this DHCP (as it would make them go into the same network as the server) and building a public VPN from the server to the clients (using authentication for security of both server´s and client networks) but I don´t know if any of those solutions suits my needs / can be applied for this scenario or if there is a better solution to be applied.

Comment: DHCP does not work the way you think it does. I would suggest to pay someone with a modicum of networking competency to sketch and possibly implement a solution for you - or prepare to read up on a *lot* of networking topics.

Comment: @vidarlo I finally implemented a VPN and its working fine. The clients are getting the configuration given by the GCP using OpenVPN, so they are connected to each other. Thanks anyway for your answer.